# Add a confirmation dialog to ASP MVC view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to have a dialog box popup letting a user know of consequences when hitting the continue button, preferably styled better than a standard browser popup.

I got jqdialog, a jquery plugin, and this was my solution:

I have a view with the following HTML:

```
<form id="formSubmit" action="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Summary/Summary") %>" method="post">
   <input type="button" name="summaryButton" id="bt-confirm" value="Continue »" />
</form>
```

and I've bound a click event to the button with some JQuery:

```
    $('#bt-confirm').click(function () {
        $.jqDialog.confirm("Are you sure want to continue?",
                function () { CallSubmit(); },  // callback function for 'YES' button
                function () { alert("This intrusive alert says you clicked NO"); }  // callback function for 'NO' button
            );
    });
```

My CallSubmit() gets called, but the form does not get submitted:

```
  function CallSubmit() {
      var submitURL = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Summary/Summary") %>';
      alert(submitURL);

      document.formSubmit.submit();   // This is NOT posting back to the controller          
  }
```

Is there a better/easier way to do this?  What is wrong with my JQuery submit?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
document.formSubmit.submit();
```

with:

```
$('#formSubmit').submit();
```

Comment: Doh!  Thanks ongle, that worked.  Also, is this a good way of doing a confirmation or is there a better way?

Comment: We do almost the same thing in our applications and it works fine.